# is a lattices with at most a single solution for a meet & join equations distributive?

Tags: lattice-orders

It is known, that in a destributive lattice, there is at most one solution for $$ a\wedge x = y \\a\vee x =z$$ for fixed $x,y,z$.

is the converse true?
namely- if there is at most one solution for any equation of this form, is the lattice distributive?

Comment: [Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties)

Comment: @bof  can you give me any clue to a proof?

Comment: Well it's easy to see that the two "prototypical" non-distributive3 lattices, the "diamond" $M_3$ and the "pentagon" $N_5,$ contains instances where the equations have two solutions. If you already know that every non-distributive lattice contains a diamond or a pentagon as a sublattice, there's your proof. I take it that you don't know that characterization of distributive lattices, and need a proof from first principles?